Git not committing, gpg stuck in database_open waiting for lock
When I attempt to commit in Git through R, I continuously get revoked access.
The error is:

gpg: Note: database_open 134217901 waiting for lock (held by 9857) ..


I have pushed.
I have pulled.
I have set a new token.
I have cloned the project.

I'm expecting the commit to send but I'm getting the full error:

gpg: Note: database_open 134217901 waiting for lock (held by 9857) ...
[GNUPG:] FAILURE sign 134250628
gpg: signing failed: Operation timed out

I'm attempting to commit a R script to GitHub through R. When I use the commit option through the panel, it will not push. I have tried to reset my credentials, put a new personal token on, and other tactics. It is not working. Not sure where to go from here. I'm expecting for the code to enter the repo and it is not.
I am stuck in a loop:
--list-keys
gpg: Note: database_open 134217901 waiting for lock (held by 9857) ...
gpg: Note: database_open 134217901 waiting for lock (held by 9857) ...
gpg: Note: database_open 134217901 waiting for lock (held by 9857) ...
gpg: Note: database_open 134217901 waiting for lock (held by 9857) ...
gpg: Note: database_open 134217901 waiting for lock (held by 9857) ...


Figured out the problem. Thanks to anyone who has taken a look. There appeared to be a merge problem and a local gpg on the file that was not needed. Removed the gpg signature and this fixed the issue.
For anyone who needs the solution:
git config --unset commit.gpgsign
git config --unset user.signingkey
git config --global commit.gpgsign false

Found another work around that allows for a permanent fix, you want to dig out the file and remove the GPG lock issues: Git Commit Freeze Due to GPG Lock Issue

Disabling commit signing is overkill, no? Figuring out what PID 9857 is up to would be better. If it's running and stuck you could unstick it; if it's dead you could clean up the stale lock.

How would I go about in fixing this issue, you reckon? I'm not sure what to do with that.

I went into htop and PID 9857 isn't running in the native terminal. It must be something in the repository that is opening it up?

I don't know much about gpg, but my guess is it's an old process that crashed and failed to release its database lock. gpg commands probably lock the database so they don't interfere with each other when multiple commands are executed simultaneously. Try googling for how to clean up a stale gpg lock. I bet there will be explanations on how to recover from this error.

Got it! You're the man. Thanks, John. For those that will need future help: Git Commit Freeze Due to GPG Lock Issues

This is not an appropriate solution, as it simply deactivate GPG signing. Refer to "Tonio" answer below for a better approach

Actually the solution above cannot be the solution, as it simply deactivates the gpg signing flag.
In my case what worked was this:
https://gist.github.com/bahadiraraz/f2fb15b07e0fce92d8d5a86ab33469f7
the error was "simply" due to a freezing during the git commit. removing the lock file, solved it immediately.
